# ReSharper Code Annotations async Task<T>

Tags: c#, .net, annotations, async-await, resharper

Is it possible to mark that the result of an `async Task<T>` can be null? Using the Attribute [CanBeNull] is not working because the return value of async Task never is null.

```
[CanBeNull] // not working...
private async Task<T> doSomeFancyAsyncStuff([NotNull] object icantbenull) { ...
```

Comment: In this case it will never be null because the compiler is wrapping your methods return value in a task - if you removed the async keyword and had to handle the Task return value yourself then I would imagine it would work just fine

Comment: I assume what you actually want is to say that the `Result` of the `Task` can be null, correct?

Comment: Do you intend to indicate that the result of the task can be null? It certainly can but the task itself cannot.

Comment: @MartinLiversage Yes this is my intension. Just to make sure resharper annoys other programmers if they are trying to use the result without checking if its not null.

Comment: I believe that your question is about [ReSharper Code Annotations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.2/Code_Analysis__Code_Annotations.html) and not [Microsoft Code Contracts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Yes, you are totally right, sorry i missed that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the Resharper `ItemCanBeNullAttribute`

> Can be appplied to symbols of types derived from IEnumerable as well as to symbols of **Task** and Lazy classes to indicate that the value of a collection item, of the **Task.Result** property or of the Lazy.Value property can be null.

[ItemCanBeNullAttribute](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html#ItemCanBeNullAttribute)

Applied to your example:

```
[ItemCanBeNull]
public async Task<string> GetSomeName() {
    var time = DateTime.Now;
    if(time.Second == 30) { 
        return "Jimmy"; 
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: That T could be null if it is a class is clear, but i want to mark it explicit using code contracts that the result `[CanBeNull]`

Comment: Are you talking about the Resharper CanBeNull attribute? A quick google brings up this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704710/canbenull-and-resharper-using-it-with-async-tasks

Comment: Could you add your comment as answer, so i can mark it? Maybe someone gets confused like me. I thought that attribute was a MS Code Contracts thing. Sorry for the confusion :)